# Why does using locals() in list comprehension does not work as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Using locals() in the list comprehension in line 3

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> [name in locals() for name in ('a', 'b')]
[False, False]
```

I would expect `[True, True]` since

```py
>>> 'a' in locals()
True
>>> 'b' in locals()
True
```

Why does this list comprehension does not work as expected?